# issue with layout xml after andorid studio update

Tags: xml, android-layout

after updating to the latest android studio, I see this weird error on mine .xml layout.
error displayed is: Couldn't resolve resource @string/path_password_strike_through
although I don't have this string resource at use anywhere on my app.

I've tried refreshing the layout and Invalidate caches/restart as some suggested, but the issue persists.

any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Strings.xml :

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">RandomIt!</string>
<string name="instructionsMainAct">Please enter your choices of numbers</string>
<string name="minValue">Start with</string>
<string name="maxValue">End with</string>
<string name="GoButton">Go!</string>
<string name="biggerVal">Start value is too big!</string>
<string name="emptyMinVal">Value cannot be empty.</string>
<string name="emptyMaxVal">Value cannot be empty.</string>
<string name="title_activity_drawer">DrawerActivity</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
<string name="nav_header_title">RandomIt App</string>
<string name="nav_header_subtitle">dblayzer@gmail.com</string>
<string name="nav_header_desc">Navigation header</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="result_parent">Your random number is:</string>
<string name="result_numberVal">Text</string>
<string name="result_tipStrVal">Tip_text</string>
<string name="default_strTip">"Sorry, your number was not selected.\nTry again next time :}"</string>
```

Comment: The problem is in your `avd_show_password.xml` which is in the folder `drawable-v21` i think, please check if this exists in your project. (referred second image of error log)

Comment: the file exists in its folder, but I don't see it anywhere on my project.

Comment: Can u post that file.

Comment: Deleting the file, resolved the error :P

Comment: Great..! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the file resolved the error.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't provide an answer? This is what worked for me and resolved the issue.